# Makefile settings leading to vtable error

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to make a simple program where I make use of templates n inheritance.
I am using Linux gcc. However, in eclipse cdt if I just give my own makefile I get an error regarding vtable undefined reference. On the other hand if I check the option in build ie **generate makefile automatically**, the error goes away. Can someone point out what could be wrong?

here are my classes with headers and makefile

AbstractVehicleFactory.h:

```
class AbstractVehicleFactory {
public:
    AbstractVehicleFactory() {}
    virtual ~AbstractVehicleFactory() {}
    IVehicle* getVehicle();

    virtual IVehicle* createVehicle() = 0;
private:
    IVehicle* mVehicle;
};
```

AbstractVehicleFactory.cpp

```
IVehicle* AbstractVehicleFactory::getVehicle() {
    if(!mVehicle) {
        mVehicle = createVehicle();
    }
    return mVehicle;
}
```

StandardVehicle.h:

```
#include "AbstractVehicleFactory.h"
template<typename T>
class StandardVehicle: public AbstractVehicleFactory {
public:
    StandardVehicle();
    virtual ~StandardVehicle();
protected :
    IVehicle* createVehicle();
private:
    T* mVehicle;
};
```

StandardVehicle.cpp:

```
template<typename T>
StandardVehicle<T>::StandardVehicle() {
    mVehicle = 0;
}

template<typename T>
StandardVehicle<T>::~StandardVehicle() {
}

template<typename T>
IVehicle* StandardVehicle<T>::createVehicle() {
    return new T();
}

Makefile:

# compiler
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

SOURCES= $(wildcard *.cpp)

OBJECTS= $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

TARGET= Vehicle.exe

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) 
        $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

all:  $(SOURCES) $(TARGET) 



clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

Error:

g++ -o Vehicle.exe AbstractVehicleFactory.o Bus.o FactoryPattern.o IVehicle.o StandardVehicle.o  
AbstractVehicleFactory.o:(.rodata._ZTV22AbstractVehicleFactory[vtable for AbstractVehicleFactory]+0x10): undefined reference to `AbstractVehicleFactory::createVehicle()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Vehicle.exe] Error 1
```

Can someone point out what could be wrong?

Edit: Even after checking makefile generate automatically, I am getting error on StandardVehicle constructor as undefined reference. StandardVehicle.o does not show any components too. Isnt it building properly?

Comment: Could you sort out in your question which code belongs to which compilation units/header files?

Comment: Its just a single folder containing all these files. Apart from these IVehicle and Bus classes  are there. They are just interface and final product respectively and the factory should return the final product based on template class defined. Like this                         AbstractVehicleFactory* a = new StandardVehicle<Bus>();
    IVehicle* v = a->createVehicle();

Comment: I've been asking you to point out which code is place in which concrete file, just precede your sample code (parts) with s.th. like `AbstractVehicleFactory.cpp:`. Edit your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code says:

```
public:
StandardVehicle() ;
```

You can't do that because its a template.  You must have the body there in the .h

When you later use a template in another cpp file like this:

```
StandardVehicle<int>   myvar ;
```

The compiler is going to make all the code for `StandardVehicle<int>` right there on the spot, so it can't refer to code in StandardVehicle.cpp

Comment: oh thanks, but I had to put all function definitions in header file for template class. Any particular reason for it?  Thanks in advance.